# Anaconda Jupyter Notebook Kernel error ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I had python 3.8 and jupyter notebook running in visual studio code before.  After I installed Anaconda, I cannot run jupyter notebook any longer and am getting a Kernel error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1704, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 69, in post
model = yield maybe_future(
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run
value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 98, in create_session
kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run
value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel_for_session
kernel_id = yield maybe_future(
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run
value = future.result()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 176, in start_kernel
kernel_id = await maybe_future(self.pinned_superclass.start_kernel(self, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 186, in start_kernel
km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 337, in start_kernel
kernel_cmd, kw = self.pre_start_kernel(**kw)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 286, in pre_start_kernel
self.write_connection_file()
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 466, in write_connection_file
self.connection_file, cfg = write_connection_file(self.connection_file,
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 136, in write_connection_file
with secure_write(fname) as f:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 461, in secure_write
win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 387, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I have tried `conda install ipykernel --update-deps` and `conda install pywin32` but the issue persists.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi I did Google for this, but I didn't see the link you posted.  I will give it a try.  Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much Tim Roberts.  Valentin Verschinin's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This suggestion worked for me: pip uninstall pywin32 and then conda install it again:
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4980#issuecomment-663885620

how to use pip from conda:
Open Anaconda.
Select Environments in the left hand pane below home.
Just to the right of where you selected and below the "search environments" bar, you should see base(root). Click on it.
A triangle pointing right should appear, click on it an select "open terminal"
Use the regular pip install command here.

then how to install pywin32 using anaconda:
ran conda install from anaconda prompt as admin  per this website, https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pywin32 :

conda install -c anaconda pywin32